# Addition table guava and arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, guava

I have this program and I want to gather values in ArrayList `operatCible` and values in Table `employeeYearsOfService` and I want to stock the result in `HashMap<String,integer>` witch contains RowKey and result.

I don't know how to do it. This what I want

[image: result]

**Code**

```
    public class collaborativAlgorithme {

    Table<String, String, Double> employeeYearsOfService = 
    HashBasedTable.create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> operatCible = new ArrayList<Double>();
    operatCible.add(4.1);
    operatCible.add(5.0);
    System.out.println(operatCible);

    Table<String, String, Double> employeeYearsOfService = 
    HashBasedTable.create();

    employeeYearsOfService.put("AT&T", "Stacy Lerner", 1.4);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Microsoft", "Stacy Lerner", 3.5);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Microsoft", "Bill Smith", 13.2);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Google", "Stacy Lerner", 11.5);

    employeeYearsOfService.put("AT&T", "Bill Smith", 2.0);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Google", "Bill Smith", 9.75);
    System.out.println(employeeYearsOfService.rowKeySet());
    HashMap<String,Integer> result=new HashMap<String,Integer>;
    System.out.println(employeeYearsOfService);
    Map<String, Double> attEmployees = employeeYearsOfService.row("AT&T");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> employee : attEmployees.entrySet()) {
        // what i do??
        // sum values arraylist and values table
        System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employee.getKey() + ", Years 
     of Service: " + employee.getValue());
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Not celar what you're trying to do - you have values, just sum them? Why `Integer` in map, not `Double`? What's the deal with `operatCible` and its values?

Comment: @Xaerxess i want just sum the values, i have mistaken  `Double` in map, the deal is i want sum values in `ArrayList` with values in `Table`

Comment: So just sum the numbers you have in your loop in `employee.getValue()` with those in the list? Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @Xaerxess thank you, but if i want sum every row in my `Table` not only for `employeeYearsOfService.row("AT&T")`,how do it, i'm begginerin Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem 
And I add something else as (sqrt)....
   this is the code

```
    int k = 0;
    Double sum = 0.0;//cosine similarity
    Double sum2 = 0.0;
    System.out.println(employeeYearsOfService);
    for (String key : employeeYearsOfService.rowKeySet()) {
        HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        for (Entry<String, Double> employee : 
        employeeYearsOfService.row(key).entrySet()) {
            sum += employee.getValue() * operatCible.get(k);
            sum2+=employee.getValue();
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;

        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.println(sqrt(sum2));
        hm.put(key, sum);
        sum = 0.0;

        System.out.println(hm);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you ca dou that

```
         HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
         System.out.println(employeeYearsOfService);
         for (String key : employeeYearsOfService.rowKeySet()) {

        for (Entry<String, Double> employee : 
        employeeYearsOfService.row(key).entrySet()) {
            sum += employee.getValue() + operatCible.get(k);

            k++;
        }
        k = 0;

        System.out.println(sum);


        hm.put(key, sum);


    }
```